# Authorizing Salesforce from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, salesforce, authorization

I'm new to VS Code and am not Tech professional. When attempting to connect VS Code to my Salesforce sandbox, I continually receive a "proxy" related error. Here's a copy of the output from VS Code:

10:53:01.154 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias Larry Dev --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  connect ETIMEDOUT 13.108.232.3:443
10:53:39.474 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias Larry Dev --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1

My Proxy settings in VS Code are as follows: http://proxy.kdc.capitalone.com:8099

The browser response I'm receiving is: This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The browser response URL I'm receiving is: http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code=aPrxa8HQGmZn7E8rvcIpewa2fL4CooKkj1C4g8uByPKnLtVExljf1tmLACz6hcSBcDbJhb6Gww%3D%3D&state=9f150cdce50c

I'm not sure what else I can share with you to assist in troubleshooting this issue but let me know.

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Please check what network security software is installed on your computer and update in the question. e.g. Forcepoint Endpoint. These may be the source of the problem.